# How to make space between element in Command prompt/Bash during output?

Tags: python, shell, scrapy, command

I'm using Python and Scrapy. And when I get an output in my console it usually looks something like this:

```
<Onion, Cheese> bla bla bla, <Eggs, mustard> bla bla bla, <chicken, tomato> bla bla bla
```

How can I make space between the elements in the console?

I somehow don't know the English word for making the space with Enter button.

Comment: I've removed the `PowerShell` tag since it seems unrelated to the question. Please, re-add it if your question is actually related.

Answer (score 1):

> making the space with the Enter button

It would be helpful if we could see your code, however I believe the English word you are looking for is newline. Add a newline via `\n`.

For example:

```
print("<Onion, Cheese> bla bla bla,\n<Eggs, mustard> bla bla bla")
```